# Twitter get latest tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

How can i get the latest tweet of user with screen name? 
I want to use it the framework of Jquery

maybe like this

```
$.post("getTweet",{screenname:blabla},function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: http://www.jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.ogNhonXv.dpbs

Comment: https://github.com/sonnyt/tweetie

Comment: @user7929528 i want to get this result inner a object